# Python: store expected Exceptions in function attributes

Tags: python, function, exception, attributes

Is it pythonic to store the expected exceptions of a funcion as attributes of the function itself? or just a stinking bad practice.

Something like this

```
class MyCoolError(Exception):
    pass

def function(*args):
    """
    :raises: MyCoolError

    """
    # do something here
    if some_condition:
        raise MyCoolError

function.MyCoolError = MyCoolError
```

And there in other module

```
try:
    function(...)
except function.MyCoolError:
    #...
```

**Pro:** Anywhere I have a reference to my function, I have also a reference to the exception it can raise, and I don't have to import it explicitly.

**Con:** I "have" to repeat the name of the exception to bind it to the function. This could be done with a decorator, but it is also added complexity.

## EDIT

Why I am doing this is because I append some methods in an irregular way to some classes, where I think that a mixin it is not worth it. Let's call it "tailored added functionality". For instance let's say:

- `Class A` uses method `fn1` and `fn2`
- `Class B` uses method `fn2` and `fn3`
- `Class C` uses `fn4` ...
- And like this for about 15 classes.

So when I call `obj_a.fn2()`, I have to import explicitly the exception it may raise (and it is not in the module where classes A, B or C, but in another one where the shared methods live)... which I think it is a little bit annoying. Appart from that, the standard style in the project I'm working in forces to write one import per line, so it gets pretty verbose.

In some code I have seen exceptions stored as class attributes, and I have found it pretty useful, like:

```
try:
    obj.fn()
except obj.MyCoolError:
    ....
```

Comment: To what end would having a function store its possible exceptions get you? "Polymorphic" catching? Perhaps you could explain a use case where this would save you a lot of extra work?

Comment: As I said, it would let me use the function in any module and under any condition (e.g. the function has been added as a method to a class), with access to its exceptions withouth having to import the exceptions themselves.

Comment: Do you pass functions around a lot? It's an interesting idea, but for functions specifically, you would usually just do something like `from module import function, MyCoolError` instead. For classes, it might make more sense.

Comment: Note that you would *have* to add this fact in the documentation too. I'd *never* think that the exception is accessible that way. Also, I don't really see how it makes sense to pass around a function, considering that you could pass around the exception too so I don't really see your point. I just see a more verbose and complex way of achieving the same effect.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman, in this very case, I have some functions shared by some classes on an "irregular basis", (class `A` has `fn1` and `fn2`, class `B` has `fn1` and `fn3`, class `C` only `fn2`, etc), and to avoid a explosion of mixins, I prefer to append the very methods I need to the classes that need it. That said, when I call `obj.fn1()`, I have to explicitly import its possible exceptions, which I find it a little bit annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not Pythonic.  I also think that it does not provide a lot of advantage over the standard way which should be to just import the exception along with the function.

There is a reason (besides helping the interpreter) why Python programs use `import` statements to state where their code comes from; it helps finding the code of the facilities (e. g. your exception in this case) you are using.

The whole idea has the smell of the declaration of exceptions as it is possible in C++ and partly mandatory in Java.  There are discussions amongst the language lawyers whether this is a good idea or a bad one, and in the Python world the designers decided against it, so it is not Pythonic.

It also raises a whole bunch of further questions.  What happens if your function A is using another function B which then, later, is changed so that it can throw an exception (a valid thing in Python).  Are you willing to change your function A then to reflect that (or catch it in A)?  Where would you want to draw the line — is using `int(text)` to convert a string to int reason enough to "declare" that a `ValueError` can be thrown?

All in all I think it is not Pythonic, no.